# Two domain pointing to html folder want to redirect to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two domain that are pointing to same IP

1. www.abc.com
2. beta.xyz.com

The are both going to `var/www/html` directory. I want to send

1. **www.abc.com** to `var/www/html/live`
2. **beta.xyz.com** to `var/www/html/beta`

Comment: Please explain what you tried. This site is not a wish list where you just drop off your requirement, and someone else will do all the work for you.

Comment: Create a separate Virtual Host for this and mention the respective directory path in it.

Comment: I was trying to tackle it with .htaccess mod_rewrite but it wasn't working @04FS 
In the end i created two virtual host on my server and pointed them to there respected folders.